# Creating multiroot json file

Tags: php, json

I want to create one json file with arrays encoded as json line by line. So it would look something like this:

```
{...valid json 1...}
{...valid json 2...}
```

But when I use simple fwirte with "/n" flag to do this, I get an unexpected EOF in the first line of the json file. Like I couldnt create jsons one by one in a file, that has a .json extension.

Whats wrong, and how can I fix it?

EDIT. Sample code that I use:

```
$file = fopen("output.json", "w");

$arr = ['a', 'b'];

fwrite($file, json_encode($arr), "\n");

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Please post some of your code for writing & reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

according to the manual, [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php) does accept the following three arguments:

```
resource $handle
string $string
int $length (optional)
```

So you would have to do the following:

```
$file = fopen("output.json", "w");

$arr = ['a', 'b'];

fwrite($file, json_encode($arr) . "\n");

fclose($file);
```

Note that the string concatenation operator is `.` (simply a dot)

Comment: When does the error occur, and which error? If it's on code you haven't yet posted, please post more code.

Comment: JSON is only a format, it cannot raise errors. Only parsing the JSON can. So the question is: where is your JSON parsed?

Comment: Netbeans parses is automatically and checks for errors.

Comment: AFAIK JSON does not allow multiple roots. This would contradict its name

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Atmoscreations answer:

Your output format is technically not valid JSON. If you want to store a list of values/objects, you should encapsulate everything in a JSON list:

```
[    
    {...valid json 1...},
    {...valid json 2...},
    ...
    {...valid json N...}
]
```

You can do this with your PHP objects:

```
$file = fopen("output.json", "w");
$arr = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd'],
];
fwrite($file, json_encode($arr));
fclose($file);
```